# Limiting Matrices of Markov Chains with different submatrix dimensions.

Tags: probability, matrices, markov-chains

From what little I know of Markov chains that I got from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhnFHnLkrfA),

The formula for calculating the fundamental matrix is $F = (I - Q)^{-1}$.
However, how would one go about subtracting submatrices I and Q if they had different dimensions? In other words, if the number of absorbing states was different that the number of non-absorbing states.

Example:

```
[

    [1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
    [0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0],
    [0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0],
    [0,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0],
    [0,   0,   0, 1/2,   0, 1/2],
    [0, 3/9, 2/9,   0, 4/9,   0]
]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the relevant context from this off-site video in your question. Your questions should be self-contained: don’t force people to go chasing links that might go stale to understand them.

Comment: The identity matrix in that formula is not a submatrix of the transition matrix. It’s always sides appropriately for $Q$, so they can’t have different dimensions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, we have 4 absorbing state and 2 transient.
$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/2\\
4/9 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So
$$
(I - Q) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1/2\\
-4/9 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
(I - Q)^{-1} = \frac{9}{7} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1/2\\
4/9 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: So if I'm understanding it correctly, the identity matrix will actually always have the dimensions of Q but with zeros at every position except for the diagonal.

Comment: Yes, exactly. In this case it is a 2 x 2 matrix. A good (and freely available resource) is chapter 11 of Grindstead's probability book: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf specifically on pg 416